# Angular2 ElementRef gets null after accessing any of its methods?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

i'am stuck on a problem a cant grasp around my head :)

I have a service shared between 2 components, and i'am passing ElementRef from second (child) to first component (parent) - everything seems ok, but as soon as i try to call for example scroller.nativeElement i get this exception:
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.scroller is null

```
// this is working
this.repositionSubscription = this.sharedService.repositionAction$.subscribe(scrollable => {
console.log('resize');
console.log(scrollable);// here looks ok, firebug gives me nice element
});
```

but as soon as i change it to

```
// this is not working
this.repositionSubscription = this.sharedService.repositionAction$.subscribe(scrollable => {
console.log('resize');
scrollable.nativeElement.whatever(); 
});
```

i don't get how it's possible ? 
similiar problem exists if i omit service (as i first did) and try to do it like this:

```
this.scroller = this.dialog.nativeElement.querySelector('paper-dialog-scrollable'); 
console.log(this.scroller); // works fine

this.scroller = this.dialog.nativeElement.querySelector('paper-dialog-scrollable');
this.scroller.nativeElement.whatever(); // not working, exception as above
```

//EDIT to provide more information, 
Parent controller

```
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private sub: any;
    public id: number;
    @ViewChild('dialog') dialog: any;
    private scroller: ElementRef;
    private repositionSubscription:Subscription;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private sharedService: SharedService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        console.log('User Detail Component Init');

        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

            this.id = +params['id'];
            this.dialog.nativeElement.open();

        });

        this.repositionSubscription = this.sharedService.repositionAction$.subscribe(scrollable => {
          //Reposition paper dialog
          scrollable.nativeElement.dialogElement =this.dialog.nativeElement; // error, scrollable is null, but with commenting that line, and doing console.log(scrollable) i get proper element, only when i try to use that variable my app is throwing exception as described before
          this.dialog.nativeElement.notifyResize();
        });
}
```

child component is just getting @ViewChild scrollable and passing it with `this.sharedService.repositionDialog(this.scrollable);`

and shared service looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  // Observable navItem source
  private reposition = new BehaviorSubject<ElementRef>(null);
  // Observable navItem stream
  repositionAction$ = this.reposition.asObservable();
  // service command
  repositionDialog(scrollable:ElementRef) {
    this.reposition.next(scrollable);
  }
}
```

in first place i was trying to just get ViewChild/ContentChild of that nested component but i can't get it to work. Components are loaded to router-outlet, so maybe that's why ? I think that would be cleanest way to do it, but as i couldnt get it to work i tried with service - still not working thou.
thanks for help

Comment: Can you post the Observer of `this.sharedService.repositionAction$` and any other code relevant to the Observable/Subject and the ElementRef?

Comment: I don't know what causes your error but I'd suggest not passing `ElementRef` around. Rather provide an observable that emits events with commands using a service and subscribe from within the component the `ElementRef` belongs to, and do there with `ElementRef` what you need to be done depending of the emitted command.

Comment: i have provided more info about my problem. Günter, i'am sorry but i don't know how to subscribe to ElementRef, do you mean with @ContentChildren ? I tried some examples found here but none was working for me, as i couldnt find one with router-outlet implementation, all of them was just getting elements from nested components not loaded with router.